# Onebox for nonexistent user's question looks ugly

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

[Liveupdate phone number forms and test for international numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/improve-this-code-liveupdate-phone-number-forms-and-test-for-international-numb) - that guy has a rather long nick and no gravatar since he doesn't have an account on Code Review. A part of his nick is shown below the tag which looks pretty ugly:

[image: ugly]

Comment: Unregistered users technically do have accounts - in this case, the user doesn't even have an account on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fixed now](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1004471#1004471), thanks.

Note that the nickname appearing there is the browser showing the alt text for a broken image. Some browsers don't even show it at all. Either way, there's not much we can do about the positioning of these alternative texts. Well, except not create broken images in the first place.